# List join column as null value if there is no match in the other table

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is simple: I want to list everything from my "form" table and if there aren't any matches to this "form" in the "outstanding" table, then this row should be also listed only with NULL in the PAYED_GROSS_AMOUNT column (the "outstanding" table is used for example for this column). Right now with this query all I get are the "form" matches, which have also matching entries in the "outstanding" table:

```
SELECT 
    `f`.`ID`                            AS `ID`,
    `f`.`FORM_NR`                           AS `form_nr`,
    `f`.`DELIVERY_DATE`                         AS `delivery_date`,
    `f`.`FORM_DATE`                         AS `form_date`,
    `f`.`PAYMENT_DATE`                      AS `payment_date`,
    MAX(`os`.`PAYED_DATE`)                      AS `payed_date`,
    `fi`.`GROSS_MONEY`                          AS `gross_money`,
    `fi`.`NET_PRICE`                        AS `net_price`,
    ifnull(SUM(`os`.`PAYED_GROSS_AMOUNT`), 0)                       AS `payed_gross_amount`,
    ifnull((`fi`.`GROSS_MONEY`  
     - SUM(`os`.`PAYED_GROSS_AMOUNT`)),
     `fi`.`GROSS_MONEY`)                        AS `remaining_amount`
    FROM  `form` `f`
    LEFT JOIN `outstanding` `os` ON `f`.`ID` = `os`.`INVOICE_ID`,
    (SELECT form_id          AS `FORM_ID`, 
                  SUM(gross_money) AS `GROSS_MONEY`, 
                  SUM(net_price)   AS `NET_PRICE` 
           FROM   form_item
           GROUP  BY form_id) fi
    WHERE `f`.SUBTYPE <> 3
    AND   `fi`.FORM_ID = `f`.ID
    AND   `f`.STATUS = 2
    AND   `f`.DIRECTION = 1
    AND   `os`.DELETED <> 'deleted' 
    AND   (`f`.PAYMENT_TYPE = 2 OR `f`.PAYMENT_TYPE = 4)
    AND   `f`.FORM_TYPE = 'Invoice'
    AND `f`.deleted <> 'deleted' 
    GROUP BY `f`.`ID`, 
             `fi`.`form_id` 
    ORDER BY `f`.`FORM_DATE` DESC;
```

I also tried with LEFT OUTER JOIN but with no luck :(

Thank you!

EDIT:

Query simplified as possible (you can ignore the WHERE clauses in the end)

Expected result:

form table:

```
ID FORM_NR ...
1  2019/1
2  2019/2
3  2019/4
4  2019/7
...
```

outstanding table:

```
INVOICE_ID  PAYED_DATE  PAYED_GROSS_AMOUNT ...
2           2019-02-05  100
3           2019-02-06  200
...
```

Result:

```
FORM_NR  FORM_DATE  ... PAYED_DATE  PAYED_GROSS_AMOUNT
2019/1   2019-02-01     null        0
2019/2   2019-02-02     2019-02-05  100
2019/4   2019-02-03     2019-02-06  200
2019/7   2019-02-04     null        0
...
```

PAYED_GROSS_AMOUNT is because of the IFNULL method 0 and not NULL.

Comment: I am surprised this query even runs, because I seem to be finding many syntax errors.  You should post a _minimal_ query, just large enough to get across your point.

Comment: I simplified it a little, maybe not enough? It runs I can confirm that, where do you see syntax errors?

Comment: update your query with sample data and desired output result

Comment: You have inner join with table partner, what is the output for records which has entries in both forms and partners but not in address_data

Comment: Or just ignore the advice offered and carry on regardless

Comment: Sure, I will edit the question with table examples and expected results, no problem.

Comment: The syntax is `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, i.e. the `OUTER` keyword is optional - and makes no difference.

Comment: Question edited with expected result, sample data and even more simplified query

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS`.  Something like this:

```
select . . .
from form f
where <conditions on form> and
      not exists (select 1
                  from outstanding o
                  where o.form_item = f.id and
                        <conditions on outstanding>
                 );
```